# Aligning the tabs in two rows using .tabset in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, tabs, r-markdown

I have the following code and would like the tabs to appear over two rows such that

```
row 1: `A Plot`, `B Plot`, `C Plot`
row 2: `A Table`, `B Table`, `C Table`
```

How is this achieved?

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

## Plots {.tabset}

### A plot

### B plot
 
### C plot

### A Table           # New line

### B Table

### C Table
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be using [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to align the tabs in three column.

````
---
title: "Tabset in Two Row"
output: html_document
---

```{css, echo=FALSE}

.break .nav-tabs {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  text-align: center;
}

.break .nav-tabs:before,
.break .nav-tabs:after {
  content: unset;
}
```

## Plots {.tabset .break}

### A plot

### B plot
  
### C plot

### A Table

### B Table

### C Table
````

---

[image: tabs in a three column grid layout]

---